# Как сделать 301 редирект для подкаталогов WordPress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, редирект

Добрый вечер, суть вопроса:
Имеется сайт созданный через wp multisite - `doma.in/site1`. Я хочу переименовать его в `doma.in/site2`.

Как сделать 301 редирект, чтобы все внутренние ссылки перенаправляли на новый сайт в подкаталоге?

К примеру чтобы: `doma.in/site1/sub1/sub2/` перенаправлял на `doma.in/site2/sub1/sub2/`.

*Правки*

При использование команды:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*site1.*
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ https://doma.in/site2/$1? [R=301,L]
```

`doma.in/site1/` успешно перенаправляет на сайт `doma.in/site2/`.
Но при этом ссылки вида `doma.in/site1/123/321/` не перенаправляют на `doma.in/site2/123/321/`. А также ссылка без слэша`doma.in/site1` не перенаправляет на `doma.in/site2/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request is on the old domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.doma\.in$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.doma.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо, можно уточнить в этом коде содержится редирект /site1/ на /site2/?

Comment: по идеи да, проверьте должно работать

Comment: проверьте и если не сложно напиши результат

Comment: Дополню сейчас вопрос, так как происходят некие непонятные редиректы.

Comment: в адресной строке вы пишите домейн так - perviy1.ru

Comment: так для второй ссылки надо написать тоже самое как для первой

Comment: Я сделал правки в вопросе, с использованием Вашего примера. Другие домены трогать не буду так как это усложнит вопрос и понимание вопроса. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить вопрос (потратив на это весь день) путем использования данного кода:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doma.in
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*site1.*
RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ https://doma.in/site2/$1? [R=301,L]
```